# unable to start Websphere Application server from RAD

Tags: websphere, rad

I am using `WAS` 6.1 for my application development. I have created profiles and configured the `JDBC` providers and datasource. When i was trying to start the `WAS` from `RAD`, i am getting a time out error along with the below information in the `RAD` console:

```
Usage: AppServer/java/bin/java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  AppServer/java/bin/java [-jar] [-options] jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -cp -classpath <directories and zip/jar files separated by ;>
              set search path for application classes and resources
    -D<name>=<value>
              set a system property
    -verbose[:class|gc|jni]
              enable verbose output
    -version  print product version
    -version:<value>
        require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
              include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
              see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
              load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
    -? -help  print this help message
    -X        print help on non-standard options
    -assert   print help on assert options*
```

anyone is having any idea?

Comment: How exactly are you trying to start it?

Answer (score 1):

Got the same error, it's a bug with RAD creating a buggy script to optimized Websphere server for development.

One workaround is to **disable RAD script generation for Websphere**.

Double click on your Websphere instance (in the server view), then on the bottom left, uncheck the select box:

> - Server
>     -> Optimize server start for development:
>
> --> [ ] "Start server with a generated script".

Then you should be able to start your server in RAD.

More info on this issue on the [IBM website](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21460336).

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, but it shouldn't solve the problem